# Pass javascript output to a html <div> as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a m_template.html file which has a script as follow:

```
<script>
     $("#id_country").change(function () {
          var countryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
          $.ajax({  // initialize an AJAX request
                url: '/ajax/ajax_load_cities',
                data: {
                     'countries': countryId   // add the country id to the GET parameters
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) { // here data comes from url output or load_cities function
                   $("#preview-items").html(data.tags);  
                   }
             });
           });
</script>
```

In the same template.html I defined a section like:

```
<div id="preview-items">
     {% for item in itemslist %}
          <label class="btn btn-primary mr-1">
                 <input type="checkbox"  id="checklist" value="{{ item.0 }}">
                  <span>
                     {{ item.1 }}
                  </span>
          </label>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and load_cieties:

```
def load_cities(request):
    ....
    
    data = {
        'tags': list(cities)
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**Where problem happens:**

The problem is in the line `$("#preview-items").html(data.tags);` which rather than passing list, replaces list in the `<div>` so at the moment I have something like:

> id1name1,id2name2,id3name3,...

**My Question:**

How to pass `data.tags` which is a list of tuples to  section as a parameter that within which I be able to style list items as I already defined in ?

`data.tags` is something like `[(id1, name1), (id2, name2), (id3, name3), ..]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a bit more sophisticated code (like React), but would this solve the immediate issue?

First, javascript doesn't have tuples, so send it a list of lists (json) from python: `[['id1', 'name1'], ['id2', 'name2'], ['id3', 'name3']];`

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#preview-items').html('');
    
    for (var i in data) {
      console.log(i, data);
      $('#preview-items').append(`
        <label class="btn btn-primary mr-1"> 
          <input type="checkbox"  id="checklist" value="` + data[i][0] + `"> 
          <span> 
             ` + data[i][1] + ` 
          </span> 
        </label><br />` 
      );
    }
}
```

(Note the use of backticks in the javascript multi-line string)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried with both  # and #preview-items, but didn't work!